# How can I create the logger with an enricher in my baseclass that has to use something in the class?

Tags: serilog

I was using the following in my static constructor of the base class

```
    static ApplicationBase()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile(
                new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(),
                @"c:\logs\log-{Date}.txt", fileSizeLimitBytes: 4194304)) 
            .CreateLogger();
    }
```

Now I need to attach one of our own custom enricher. The enricher is expecting a function that must use a modifier of the actual Application class.

For example, I need to do

```
    .Enrich.WithStoreData(()=>GetStoreData)
```

Well, it doesn't have to be a function, the bottom line is, the call of GetStoreData is using an object instantiated in the actual child application class (and I cannot change the lifecycle of that object), so I can't access the object from the static constructor.

That means I have to move the logger creation to the normal base constructor. Because it has many children, how can I ensure the logger creation is executed only once? That means I have to apply a lock and check if the logger has been created already. That's really ugly.

And I am not using any container like autofac, so I will not want to create a wrapper of the logger.

At this point, I can only think of the idea creating the logger in the base constructor, and protect it with a lock.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use enrichment while configuring Serilog, and if you are configuring your static logger in your base class, then you cannot change the enrichment later at run time.

But you can use *Contextual loggers* at run time to add additional properties to your logger: [Serilog Context and Correlation](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/)

**Adding Log Context**

```
// Log.Logger is initialized in your static base 
var StudentLogger = Log.Logger.ForContext<Student>();
StudentLogger.Error(/* log message */);
```

**Adding correlation:**

```
// Log.Logger is initialized in your static base 
var orderId = "some value";
var corrLog = Log.Logger.ForContext("orderId", orderId)
corrLog.Error(/* log message */);
```